# SizeToContent disables EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make window size same as content, but when I use `SizeToContent`, it for some reason breaks my `EventTrigger` and it no longer invokes the command when the window is loaded.

Code sample:
WindowView:

```
<Window x:Class="Tasks.Views.TasksWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tasks.Views"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Tasks.ViewModels"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Tasks.Views"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TasksWindow">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadTasksCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:TasksViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Views:TasksControl/>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TasksViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TaskModel> _tasks
        = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>();

    public IEnumerable<TaskModel> Tasks
    {
        get { return _tasks; }
    }
    public ICommand LoadTasksCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(LoadTasks); }
    }
    public void LoadTasks()
    {
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, "Tasks.xml");

        // Check if save file exists
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            return;

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TaskList));
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Tasks.xml"))
        {
            TaskList results = (TaskList)xs.Deserialize(reader);

            foreach (var item in results.TasksList)
                _tasks.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Base:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action) { _action = action; }

    public void Execute(object parameter) { _action(); }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Model:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfTaskModel")]
public class TaskList
{
    [XmlElement("TaskModel")]
    public List<TaskModel> TasksList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TaskModel : ObservableObject
{

    private string _name;
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, once I've added the stuff you left out and which is required to get a working program. Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: well, I can't. The fact remains that the post above is insufficient to completely describe the problem. If you think you can improve the post, so that it includes an [mcve] and enough information that _anyone_ can reproduce the problem, great. I encourage you to do so. Otherwise, this question is not useful. If you think it's answerable, then you should answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well, we've got two people with the same problem. OP isn't delusional or goofy. The cause isn't obvious. It's obviously answerable, but I don't happen to know what the answer is. It's common for questioners not to have a complete understanding of how to reproduce the issue, and that shouldn't be surprising in a sample of people who are asking questions they don't know the answers to. The key to reproducing it is quite likely the answer to the question in this case, or very close to it.

Comment: @Ed: _"OP isn't delusional or goofy"_ -- huh? what makes you think that even needs to be said? The problem here is that there is not enough information in the question to reproduce the problem. And frankly, your telling _me_ that you can reproduce it adds nothing either. That you can reproduce it has no relevance to me, unless you use your ability to reproduce it **to improve the question**. And then, only to the extent that the question is improved.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm afraid we're going to have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: I don't know the reason of this issue. I'm new WPF, so I suspected mostly that my mistake is somewhere inside XAML file. When I get home I will try add more samples.

Comment: @Ed: _"I'm afraid we're going to have to agree to disagree on this one"_ -- if you insist. I'm still not clear on _what_ you and I are in disagreement about. I've not disputed that you can reproduce the problem; just that saying so to me isn't helping anything. You haven't made any effort to explain how it is you think that making that statement has helped. So...oh well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question's fine. OK? And I grew weary of this conversation about... let's see, "52 mins ago", it says. "Let agree to disagree" is a polite way people have of saying "this is going nowhere; let's just drop it".

Comment: I added more code, and even with this sample code I still get same issue. I still would appreciate if you guys could help me.